# Compare two cell's values in same column while being entered

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to do it with a button. I need to press the button to check.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, temp As Integer, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To rng.Count
    For j = i + 1 To rng.Count
       If rng.Cells(j) < rng.Cells(i) Then
          MsgBox "Alert -Entry in row is Less Than Previous Cell !!"
          Exit Sub
       End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I need while I am entering values they should be compared same time.

Comment: Look into the worksheet_change event

Comment: Also have a look at [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) This should be possible without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without VBA just using the built in data validation of Excel:
See [Apply data validation to cells](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249).

Add a data validation eg at range A2:A100 with a custom formula `=A2>=A1` as rule. And add your message *"Alert -Entry in row is Less Than Previous Cell !!"* as Error Alert.

Comment: hI Peh i tried this works when i have a list in one column ,apply formula in

Comment: next column .but in same column i think i am making some mistake can you please post the code

Comment: @Sandeep I didn't understand you. Please be more specific you can also edit your original question to add details or an example. Screenshots can also help to illustrate your issues.